# Rss is valid, but Self reference doesn't match document location

Tags: rss

This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendations.
line 3, column 88: Self reference doesn't match document location!

```html
<atom:link href="http://localhost/blog/rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

Comment: Yes. Did you have a question?

Comment: yes, what is wrong with posted link? thx

Comment: `http://localhost/blog/rss` isn't the URL you were testing.

Comment: hmm yes i understand, but i'm testing by direct code input... (https://validator.w3.org/feed/#validate_by_input)

Comment: Yes. So you can't control the URL the validator is testing.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my previous comment, I did some research. I have added "Broken Link Checker" to my word press blog which found couple of broken links to googleplay (which have changed subsequently). After fixing the broken links, the blog was through. The error mentioned in my previous post didn't occur when checked with w3 text input method.
Even the feeder.co accepted the feed without any problem

Posting so others may find it useful.

thanks.